# Kendo React Grid Not Entering Cell Edit using reducers

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I am using Kendo React Grids and trying to get it so that when you click into a cell it edits as shown in this example: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-in-cell/.

I couldn't get it to enter edit until I tried to back off everything in my code that's not in their example.  What I determined is that it works as in the example when use use `useState`, but as soon as I switch to using `useReducer` it stops allowing edit.  However, I really need reducers as I need it to sort, etc. as well and those use the sorting functions, etc. use them.

Are there any examples of using this type of editing with reducers and sorting?

Comment: If you asked for an example on the KendoReact Forum they are generally helpful, but they will ask you to reproduce your issue in a StackBlitz first. Do you have an example using reducers that you could share?

Comment: Not off hand but I will try to create one.  Thanks.